# How to get contact details in Skype4COM?

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I am trying to grab the `FullName` and `Handler` from a contact I receive in Skype chat. I managed to get a breakpoint in this event:

```
Skype.MessageStatus += OnMessageStatus;

public void OnMessageStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status)
{
}
```

However the `Body` of `pMessage` contains:

```
"[Contacts enclosed. Please upgrade to latest Skype version to receive contacts.]"
```

Doesn't matter if I am the one sending or receiving the message is the same. My current Skype version is 6.16.64.105 (the issue still happens on 6.16.0.105)

I wonder if it is some issue with my Skype version of it is not supported anymore for some reason, or if maybe I am working on the wrong event...

Is there another event, or is there a way to grab the name and handler from a received contact?

[image: skype contact received]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the message's body problem, but you can try this to get the Handle and Fullname from the contact sending the message:

pMessage.Sender.Handle

pMessage.Sender.FullName